# how to extract out a string with SYMBOLS after a pattern in a URL string in Google BigQuery

Tags: regex, string, pattern-matching, google-bigquery

i have two possible forms of a URL string

```
http://www.abcexample.com/landpage/?pps=[Y/lyPw==;id_1][Y/lyP2ZZYxi==;id_2];[5403;ord];
http://www.abcexample.com/landpage/?pps=Y/lyPw==;id_1;unknown;ord;
```

I want to get out the `Y/lyPw==` in both examples

so everything before `;id_1` between the brackets

will always come after the `?pps=` part

What is the best way to approach this? I want to use the big query language as this is where my data sits

Comment: If you're looking for a credible and / or official answer for your bounty, Mosha's is both :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is one way to build a regular expression to do it:

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(url, r'\?pps=;[\[]?([^;]*);') FROM
(SELECT "http://www.abcexample.com/landpage/?pps=;[XYZXYZ;id_1][XYZZZZ;id_2];[5403;ord];" 
  AS url),
(SELECT "http://www.abcexample.com/landpage/?pps=;XYZXYZ;id_1;unknown;ord;"
  AS url)
```

Comment: Should matches on ? also match on & in case `pps` is not the only or first query parameter?

Answer (score 8):

You can use this regex:

```
pps=\[?([^;]+)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/kL8tZ3/1)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

The idea behind this regex is:

```
pps=    -> Look for the pps= pattern
\[?     -> might have a [ or not
([^;]+) -> store the content up to the first semi colon
```

So, for your both url this regex will match (in blue) and capture (in green) as below:

[image]

For **[BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference)** you have to use

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT('str', 'reg_exp')
```

Quoting its documentation:

> REGEXP_EXTRACT: Returns the portion of str that matches the capturing group within the regular expression.

You have to use a code like this:

```
SELECT
   REGEXP_EXTRACT(word,r'pps=\[?([^;]+)') AS fragment
FROM
   ...
```

For a working example code you can use:

```
SELECT
   REGEXP_EXTRACT(url,r'pps=\[?([^;]+)') AS fragment
FROM
(SELECT "http://www.abcexample.com/landpage/?pps=;[XYZXYZ;id_1][XYZZZZ;id_2];[5403;ord];" 
  AS url),
(SELECT "http://www.abcexample.com/landpage/?pps=;XYZXYZ;id_1;unknown;ord;"
  AS url)
```

Answer (score 2):

This regex should work for you

```
(\w+);id_1
```

It will extract `XYZXYZ`

It uses the concept of [Group capture](https://regex101.com/r/qT3xM8/1)

[See this Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qT3xM8/1)